# Screenshot with cursor

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, screen-capture

I used to take *tons* of screenshots that included the cursor with SnapzXPro. It’s stopped working in past OS releases requiring a patch, but has stopped again and I’m not sure Ambrosia is paying much attention.

I’ve been through Skitch, CloudApp, Grab, and the new mechanism migrated from iOS that uses Markup, and none let the cursor remain.

Anyone know of a way to take a screenshot that includes the cursor without editing the screenshot or having to use timers?

Answer (score 1):

The MacOS `Screenshot.app`, which can by default be summoned with <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>, has a setting to include the pointer. [image: Inception]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtBEv.jpg)